# Bash script code runs but does not return data

Tags: linux, bash, kali-linux

I've created a program to scan for directories and files in websites, but it does not return any info on the screen when I run it. I`m using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for palavra in $(cat lista.txt)
do
    resposta=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $1/$palavra/)
    resposta2=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $1/$palavra)
    if [ $resposta == "200" ]
    then
        echo "Diretorio encontrado: $palavra"
    fi
    if [ $resposta2 == "200" ]
    then
        echo "Arquivo encontrado: $palavra"
    fi
done
```

It runs, but simply returns nothing. The file "lista.txt" is in the same folder as the program and it has information, double checked it.
Someone, please, help me find what is wrong! Thanks you!

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You can inspect what values `resposta` and `reposta2` variables have.

Comment: Could you provide a content of `lista.txt` and a full command, how exactly do you run the script? There is a `$1`, so the script calls a curl, which goes to a server like `your_parameter/your_website/`.

Comment: Thank you both, I`m testing in a internal website and for some reason it is returning HTTP code 404. Just tested on google and worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Vitalii Dmitriev I`m using the comand: ./descobre.sh www.google.com and now it works.
Before, I was using ./descobre.sh www.nicetech.com.br, wich is the website of my company, and it was just returning HTTP code 404.

Answer (score 0):

After the calculation of `resposta` and `resposta2`, add the following lines of code:

```
echo "palavra   is : [$palavra]"
echo "resposta  is : [$resposta]"
echo "resposta2 is : [$resposta2]"
```

You'll see from there what to do.